# How to embed SDL video in an existing OpenGL project

Tags: c#, opengl, sdl, opentk

I'm working on an OpenGL game, and would like to play video on 3D surfaces within the game. SDL seems to be an excellent choice for video playback, but is it possible to create the surface inside of an existing OpenGL context? How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SDL has, to my knowledge, no functions for video playback; don't be fooled by API names like `SDL_Video`. Those are actually used for window management.

What you need to do is using some video decoder library to decode video into image buffers, then pass these image buffers into an OpenGL texture. The open source video player *[mplayer](http://mplayerhq.hu)* (which internally uses the ffmpeg *libavformat* and *libavcodec* libraries for video/audio decoding) also has an OpenGL video output module. I suggest you fetch the mplayer source code and take a look into the OpenGL video output module, to get an idea how to do this.

**EDIT:**

Since you're using SdlDotNet, I suggest using a `SdlDotNet.Graphics.SurfaceGl` as target surface for the `SdlDotNet.Graphics.Movie`.

Comment: There is an extension to SDL that I'm using to successfully play video.

Comment: @IDWMaster: Could you please tell me, what exactly you're using?

Comment: Use a SdlDotNet.Graphics.SurfaceGl as target surface for the SdlDotNet.Graphics.Movie; I think that should be easy enough. I'm not a .net coder so I don't really know how to do it in code though. Sorry.

Comment: I was not aware that class existed! Post that as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: @IDWMaster: Neither did I until I read the SdlDotNet documentation ;)